# How to clear the contents of a list which is inside a HashMap value using Java 8 stream

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I have a `HashMap` with the following structure.
`Map<String, Container>`

The `Container` class contains a `List`. I want to clear the contents of this list so that the list exists but with 0 elements. Later I will put values in it again.

The `replaceAll()` expects a `BiFunction`. Due to this the following is giving compilation error because return type of `clear()` is `void`:

`personMap.replaceAll((k,v) -> v.getMyList().clear());`

Comment: Why not use foreach?

Comment: `map.forEach((k, v) -> v.getList().clear());` should work , no?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use this:

```
map.values().forEach(i -> i.getMyList().clear());
```

Alternatively you can use this:

```
map.values().stream()
        .map(Container::getMyList)
        .forEach(List::clear);
```

Answer (score 3):

Iterating your `Map` with `forEach` will require a `BiConsumer<? super K, ? super V>` (where `K` and `V` are the key and value types of your `Map`), which will ultimately allow you to invoke `void` methods on the elements.

E.g.

```
personMap.forEach((k,v) -> v.getMyList().clear());
```

Comment: Shame to me!! I should have done that myself. Actually I am new to streams. Thanks a lot :)

Comment: @Sumit you're welcome :) I'd suggest you accept Samuel Philipp's answer instead of mine though. I think it's a bit better.

Comment: 1st time I have found someone so generous !!

Comment: @Sumit not really about generosity. The Q&As are for everyone. It's best to have the best answer accepted, so people who follow will see it first. Ultimately you'd want the same for Q&As you're reaching when looking for a solution.

Answer (score 0):

Why *clear* it in the first place?

```
map.forEach((k, v) -> v.setMyList(new ArrayList<>()));
```

Comment: Why insist on using `replaceAll` if you are not actually replacing anything? You could do the same with `forEach`. Also, there might be other references to the lists.

Comment: `new ArrayList()` will unnecessarily create new objects. That is why I want to clear it. But thanks anyway.

Comment: @Sumit it might turn out that creating these instances (that are very cheap) is going to be cheaper than clearing your existing instances.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, if you are targeting a specific Container : first you should use the Map.get method.

```
map.get(containerId);
```

Then, to clear the list

```
map.get(containerId).getList().clear();
```

If you want to clear them all (as suggested earlier) :

```
map.values().forEach(i -> i.getList().clear());
```